# Logging = ALL issue on PostgreSQL 9.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

So I understand that ALL will get me the SELECTS which is what I would like to monitor for my application, however, the POSTGRES daemon is running a select of its own against the database and it is logging it...

Does anyone know how to avoid this as my log will get filled rather quickly

```
LOG:  statement: SELECT
           (SELECT sum(xact_commit) + sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Transactions",
           (SELECT sum(xact_commit) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Commits",
           (SELECT sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Rollbacks"
2017-01-09 23:53:36 UTC [14264-16] evtofadmin@evtof LOG:  statement: SELECT
           (SELECT sum(xact_commit) + sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Transactions",
           (SELECT sum(xact_commit) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Commits",
           (SELECT sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Rollbacks"
2017-01-09 23:53:37 UTC [14264-17] evtofadmin@evtof LOG:  statement: SELECT
           (SELECT sum(xact_commit) + sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Transactions",
           (SELECT sum(xact_commit) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Commits",
           (SELECT sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Rollbacks"
2017-01-09 23:53:38 UTC [14264-18] evtofadmin@evtof LOG:  statement: SELECT
           (SELECT sum(xact_commit) + sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Transactions",
           (SELECT sum(xact_commit) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Commits",
           (SELECT sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Rollbacks"
2017-01-09 23:53:39 UTC [14264-19] evtofadmin@evtof LOG:  statement: SELECT
           (SELECT sum(xact_commit) + sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 16384)) AS "Transactions", ....
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only turn on logging for the application,

SQL:

`ALTER USER`*your_app_username*`SET log_statement='ALL';`

Comment: Well that seems almost too easy, which is probably why I didn't find anything in the interweb...Many thanks